# Why is this query abnormally long?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm timing various part of the site's "initialisation" code (including such things as verifying the user is logged in, connecting to the database, importing functions...)

This query is currently taking up abouve half the total initialisation time all by itself:

```
$sql = "update `users` set `lastclick`=now(),".(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,6) == "/ajax/" ? "" : " `lastactive`=now(),")." `lastip`='".addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."' where `id`=".$userdata['id'];
```

Generating the query takes no time at all, it's the running that's the problem. Example result query:

```
update `users` set `lastclick`=now(), `lastactive`=now(), `lastip`='192.168.0.1' where `id`=1
```

Simple enough query, right? I am the only user on the server right now, there is literally nothing else running. So why does a simple update take up more time than connecting to the database, `SELECT`ing the user data in the first place, validating the cookies, and defining a bunch of functions all combined?

(I just tried replacing `now()` with a literal value, but that made no difference - in fact it ended up taking 13ms the first time instead of 4...)

---

**EDIT**: As requested:

```
explain select * from  `users` where `id`=1
1 row returned

id select_type table type  possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      users const PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       const 1
```

Comment: If you have access to the database via command line or the such, I would do: EXPLAIN update `users` set `lastclick`=now(), `lastactive`=now(), `lastip`='192.168.0.1' where `id`=1; This will give you a bunch more info which would be useful for figuring out the source of your slow query. If you can't understand what the output means, just paste it here in your original post and we'll better help you out.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?  I presume you have an index on the `id` column?  Have you tried profiling the query?  @EmmanuelG: `EXPLAIN` only works with `SELECT`, but it could be worth performing `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1`.

Comment: @eggyal Explain works fine for update statements in MySQL 5.6. Perhaps it didn't before? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: @EmmanuelG: I stand corrected.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` result added for the select - trying it for the update gave a syntax error.

Comment: Make sure the `id` column is indexed. If it should be unique then make it such. INSERT and UPDATE are usually a lot slower than SELECT. You should minimize their usage as much as possible. You could use something like `memcache` to store the the information and then update the database every minute or so with new data.

Comment: @Kolink: Please try profiling the query - `SET PROFILING = 1; UPDATE ...; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;`

Comment: It's the PRIMARY key, so no worries there - I learned about indexes the hard way when my last project got a hundred thousand users and millions of game entries XD

Comment: @eggyal I am unable to profile the query. Profiling is disabled on the installation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my own mystery. Turns out one of the fields being updated (`lastactive`) was in an index, and the slowness was coming from rebuilding that index.

Since the only time that index might be used is in updating the list of users who are online, and that only happens by cron every set interval, I've dropped the index and now the query runs a heck of a lot faster.

Thanks to those who tried to help - you did help me find the problem, indirectly!